# Is it possible to set the constraint unique = True except for empty string into SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I use the following column in my table:

```
email = Column(String(60), unique=True)
```

However, I need the possibility to save empty strings in this column. Namely, I need something like this:

```
email = Column(String(60), unique=True, blank=True)
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to implement this within SQLAlchemy? What is correspondent SQL (Postgresql dialect)?

Comment: Everything other than NULL is treated as a value in PostgreSQL So even the empty string will be considered as a value for the field and will be used to run the unique constraint. If storing NULL instead of empty string works you can use `nullable=True` in the column definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try to set not an empty string, but a NULL istead. As it's said in [PostgreSql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/indexes-unique.html) NULL-values are not equals.

Comment: I know about this functionality but in any case thank you. Besides, SQLAlchemy allows directly declare
`email = Column(String(60), unique=True, nullable=True)`
I suppose that `nullable=True` is a default value but I'm not sure.
On the other hand Django allows explicitly declaring `blank=True` and it works exactly I want. Though, I suppose, there exists a SQL query and correspondent SQLAlchemy declaration setting constraint I am looking for.

Comment: Django's `blank` has nothing to do with the database, it's a flag for form objects and other related entities (like admin) to allow an empty value in the related form field. SQLAlchemy, being a database-oriented layer, doesn't concern itself with forms, so Stanislav's approach is a good replacement. Also, you are correct that `nullable` is True by default.